# string is assigned in constructor but becomes blank thereafter C++

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I encountered a problem which I am baffled with. This pertains to whether I choose to store an object, or a pointer to it.

This is my class:

```
class Test {
public:
    std::string abc;
    int x;

    Test(std::string def, int y) {
        abc = def;
        cout << abc << endl; //THIS ALWAYS GIVES "ghi"
        x = y;
    }
};
```

Storing it as a pointer:

```
    Test* T1 = &Test{ "ghi", 100 };
    cout << T1->abc << endl; //**THIS IS BLANK -- WHY!?**
    cout << T1->x << endl; //THIS GIVES 100
```

Storing it as an object itself:

```
    Test T2 = Test{ "ghi", 100 };
    cout << T2.abc << endl; //THIS GIVES "ghi"
    cout << T2.x << endl; //THIS GIVES 100
```

I'm relatively new to C++ but based on my understanding, T1->abc should dereference the pointer T1 (and therefore I have a Test object), and then access the member abc of that Test object. Since I already created the object, it should be "ghi". But this gives blank instead.

Apparently, this applies only to the string member and not the integer member, as T1->x works fine.

And the problem doesn't exist when I store the object instead of a pointer to it, as shown by the object T2.

I have checked that during construction of T1 and T2, abc is always "ghi" *inside* the constructor. Somehow, after construction, the string just disappears.

Also, based on what I read, abc = def copies the string content and not the pointer, so it probably isn't a scope issue.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b930c881.aspx makes it very clear that in either case, whether -> or . is used, assignment can be made.

Searching Google and stackoverflow did not help. Hence yours appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
class Test {
public:
    std::string abc;
    int x;

    Test(std::string def, int y) {
        abc = def;
        x = y;
    }
};

int main() {

    Test* T1 = &Test{ "ghi", 100 };
    cout << T1->abc << endl; //THIS IS BLANK -- WHY!?
    cout << T1->x << endl; //THIS GIVES 100

    Test T2 = Test{ "ghi", 100 };
    cout << T2.abc << endl; //THIS GIVES "ghi"
    cout << T2.x << endl; //THIS GIVES 100

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Test* T1 = &Test{ "ghi", 100 };` This is just wrong. Dont do this. You,re setting the pointer to the address of a temporary object (which won't exist after the semicolon on that line).

Comment: As far as I know, g++ won't even let you write code like this.

Comment: In my actual problem, I have an abstract base class, call it Test. I also have a few derived classes, but which derived class I choose to instantiate can only be determined at run time. Therefore, I am using a pointer to Test to hold the pointer to the derived classes. Hence my need for a pointer. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @emoPuppy `Test* test = new DerivedTestType1(...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This construct:

```
Test{ "ghi", 100 };
```

creates temporary variable, that you are trying to point to. This is just wrong.

If you want to store it using pointer:

```
Test* T1 = new Test{ "ghi", 100 };

cout << T1->abc << endl; //This is not blank anymore
cout << T1->x << endl;

delete T1; //Do NOT forget this!
```

---

By the way, if you are wondering, why this line:

```
cout << T1->x << endl;
```

was still evaluating to 100: when object is destroyed, all its members are also destroyed (in terms of calling their destructors). Since `x` is an `int`, its destructor in no-op and content of memory occupied by it does not change.

On the other hand, `abc` is and `std::string`, which frees allocated memory during destruction - so `T1->abc` was referring to an empty string.

Comment: Thank you (and also to the rest). Apologies for asking what turned out to be such a straightforward question. It certainly isn't easy to learn a new language. I read some advice that we should avoid using new as the non-new version automatically removes itself when it is no longer needed. So my takeaway from this is that "automatically" doesn't take into account if it is being referenced by a pointer, only if the object itself is being referred to by a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
Test* T1 = &Test{ "ghi", 100 };
```

Please don't do this. This is exactly what's causing your problem. Instead use

```
Test* T1 = new Test("ghi", 100);
```

Because the first way created a reference to a temporary object, which disappears before you try to get the string for printing.

It works for the non-pointer because you're giving the temporary object to a new object.

don't remember to delete (because you've used new)

```
delete T1;
```

---

Or, as πάντα ῥεῖ pointed out, what would be safer, and better c++ coding practice, would be to use a [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory). The most relevant one that comes to mind is unique_ptr.

```
std::unique_ptr<Test> T1(new Test());
std::cout << T1->abc << std::endl;
...
```

Comment: Note that you have to `delete T1;` afterwards

Comment: _"Instead use ..."_ No that would result in the same dilemma.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no it wouldn't because the pointer will no longer be taking an address from a temporary object

Comment: @OlivierPoulin Ah' I didn't spot the new, I was just focused about parenthesis `()` or braces `{}`. Using `new` solves the primary problem, though isn't very good advice.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ why isn't it very good advice? what would you use instead?  (side-note: i cant find much on curly-braces vs parantheses, can you point me to some docs? )

Comment: @OlivierPoulin _"what would you use instead? "_ A smart pointer  from [these varieties](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82992/discussion-between-olivier-poulin-and--).

Comment: @OlivierPoulin _"Let us continue this discussion in chat."_ No! There won't be any ongoing discussion. I said all things necessary.

Comment: @OlivierPoulin Well, proposing `new` without recommendations how to `delete` actually ***is bad advice***, I can't help.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sure, i should add that he delete his pointer (ill do that right now) but telling him to use smart pointers is **completely irrelevant** to his question. Using new with a pointer is the _most_ relevant answer in the scope of his question.

Comment: They are just as relevant as `new` and `delete` if not _more_. Smart pointers provide ownership _and_ lifetime management. They reduce or eliminate the need to manually specify ownership or manage lifetime of an object required by `new` and `delete`. By suggesting the OP use `new` and `delete` you have made smart pointers relevant. You could have easily made it a local with automatic lifetime and taken a pointer to _that_ but instead you suggested `new` and `delete`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Ok, i'm seeing the point now. Thank you for the discussion πάντα ῥεῖ and CaptainObvlious.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>   Test* T1 = &Test{ "ghi", 100 };
> ```

The temporary *rvalue* of `Test{ "ghi", 100 }` immediately goes out of scope and ceases to exist after this statement.

Thus dereferencing it like

```
 cout << T1->abc << endl;
```

simply calls *Undefned Behavior* on a dangling pointer.

Comment: the brackets should be parentheses right? or is there something im missing?

Comment: @OlivierPoulin With the current standard both forms may be used.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet

```
Test* T1 = &Test{ "ghi", 100 };
cout << T1->abc << endl; //**THIS IS BLANK -- WHY!?**
cout << T1->x << endl; //THIS GIVES 100
```

has undefined behaviour because after statement

```
Test* T1 = &Test{ "ghi", 100 };
```

temporary object Test{ "ghi", 100 } will be deleted and the pointer becomes invalid.

A valid code could look the following way

```
Test* T1 = new Test{ "ghi", 100 };

cout << T1->abc << endl;
cout << T1->x << endl; 

delete T1;
```

Or instead of the pointer you could use a constant reference to the temporary object. For example

```
const Test &T1 = Test{ "ghi", 100 };

cout << T1.abc << endl;
cout << T1.x << endl;
```

The temporary object will be alive while the reference will be alive.